# как отсортировать многомерный массив второго уровня по сумме элекментов?

Tags: php

```
$arr = [];
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
        for ($a=0; $a<5; $a++) {
            $arr[$i][$j][$a] = rand(1, 5);
        }
    }


}
print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 3
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 3
                    [4] => 3
                )

        )
```

Если сумма элементов array[0][1] больше array[0][0], то сортировать по убыванию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
 foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    usort($x[$k], function($a,$b) { return array_sum($a) - array_sum($b); } )
 }
```

Comment: Мне надо сначала перебрать массив через цикл foreach?

Comment: а... прозевал, ку вас еще один уровень. Поправил